# Send e-mail to distribution list in Python

Tags: python, email, smtp, smtplib, distribution-list

I have a Python scripts which successfully sends e-mails to users whenever I provide a coma separated list of e-mails.

```
oSender = "My Email <my-email@company.com>"
oRecipient = pRecipient.split(",") #convert comma separated list of recipient into python list object
[...] building the e-mail body [...]
#send e-mail via smtp server
oConnexion = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.company.org',25)
oConnexion.sendmail(oSender, oRecipient, oEmail.as_string())
oConnexion.quit()
```

However, when the recipients list contains a distribution list such as `my-list@company.com`, no user from the distribution list receive anything. I do not get any error message either so I am thinking this could be related to the configuration of the distribution list itself?

Please note this is not a local distribution list created in my Outlook but rather a company wide distribution list set-up on some server.

Comment: What's up with the oPrefixes pVariable prefixes? Are you using some form of Hungarian notation?

Comment: It’s bad practice I was using when I started programming in Python to differentiate the custom objects I was creating from the objects provided by the different packages I was using... :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So discussing with our internal teams, we figured out this was because the distribution list was not configured to receive e-mails from outside our company or from anonymous applications.